# Pandas/Python equivalent of Stata's "levelsof"

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I want to get a list of all distinct or unique values of one variable in a dataframe that coincide with a specific value of another variable in that dataframe.

In Stata I would use something like:

```
levelsof(ID1) if ID2==i
```

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: Please be sure to accept one of the answers if you consider it to have answered your question (here and also on other questions you have asked in the past).  This signals to everyone whether the question remains open or not and if further answers are desired.

Answer (score 3):

Stata's `levelsof` is equivalent to pandas's `unique()`.  They both return an array of unique or distinct values.

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({ 'id1':[0,0,1,1,2,2], 
                      'id2':[5,5,5,6,6,6] })

   id1  id2
0    0    5
1    0    5
2    1    5
3    1    6
4    2    6
5    2    6

>>> df.loc[ df['id2'] == 5, 'id1' ].unique()

array([0, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Say your columns are `ID1` and `ID2`, and the DataFrame is `df`. Then

```
df.ID1[df.ID2 == i]
```

will give all the values of the first column where the second one is `i`.

Following that, you can do

```
df.ID1[df.ID2 == i].value_counts()
```

to get a breakdown,

```
df.ID1[df.ID2 == i].unique()
```

to get unique values,

```
df.ID1[df.ID2 == i].describe()
```

to get a description, and so forth (I don't know what `levelsof` is exactly).

Comment: Thanks, @JohnE <padding>